# Meteor getting values from Async function

Tags: meteor

I am having trouble with getting return value from wrapAsync function in meteor. Below is my code

```
Template.greet.helpers({
  greet : function () {
    var convertAsyncToSync  = Meteor.wrapAsync( HTTP.get );
    resultOfAsyncToSync = convertAsyncToSync('http://www.demo.com/api/greet', {} );
    console.log(resultOfAsyncToSync);
    return resultOfAsyncToSync;
  }
});
```

I get undefined value in console.

Comment: use reactiveDict or reactiveVar to save the values

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the below code but I still unable to get anything out of it.

    Template.greet.helpers({
      greet : function () {
      var convertAsyncToSync  = Meteor.wrapAsync( HTTP.get );
      resultOfAsyncToSync = convertAsyncToSync('http://www.demo.com/api/greet', function (err,   response) {
          alert('response');
          console.log(response);
          return response.data;
        } );
      }
    });

Now I response gets printed in console but nothing is returned in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Template.greet.onCreated(function(){
  this.apiResult = new ReactiveVar(null);
})
Template.greet.helpers({
  greet : function () {
    var t = Template.instance();
    HTTP.get('http://www.demo.com/api/greet', {}, function(e,r){
      //process response and save it in reactivevar
      t.apiResult.set(r.data);
    });
    return t.apiResult.get();
  }
});
```

don't forget to add package `meteor add reactive-var`

**EDIT**

```
Template.greet.onRendered(function(){
  var t = Template.instance();
  HTTP.get('http://www.demo.com/api/greet', {}, function(e,r){
    //process response and save it in reactivevar
    t.apiResult.set(r.data);
  });
})

Template.greet.helpers({
  greet : function () {
    var t = Template.instance();
    return t.apiResult.get();
  }
});
```

Comment: Does it call the HTTP.get function multiple times since my console is filled with the log.
This is what my log is showing :

Firebug's log limit has been reached. 1290 entries not shown.

Comment: if you want to do it only once do it onRendered callback

Comment: Thanks. onRendered is working but not getting how do I return a variable 'greet' from it so that I can use that in template

Comment: @Subhash, glad it works, if it is solves your problem please mark this as answer.